# When is a variable in a nested scope destroyed from the memory?

Tags: c++, variables, memory, language-concepts

```
void main() {
    int x=5;
    {
        int x= 6; 
        cout<<x;
    }
    cout<<x;
}
```

the output is 6, 5.

My question is: when  Assign x to 6, it reserved a memory cell for it, and then entered the nested block here( the old x is destroyed!! Or how it can defined two variables for the same name?

Comment: I presume thus is C++ code.  (If you don't say what the language, the question is unanswerable.)

Comment: Yes it is C++ code

Comment: Are you sure your output is `56`, not `65`? BTW, `cout>>x;` is an error - it should be `cout<<x;`.

Comment: `void main()` is **not *standard C++***. You should change it to `int main()`.

Comment: Think of those two `x`s as `x_inside_main` and `x_inside_block_inside_main`. They're two different variables. That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 3):

> how it can defined two variables for the same name?

The two `x` in your example exists in different scopes. When you defined the inner `x`, it **hides** the `x` from outer scope. See the comments in the below given program.

```
int main()
{//---------------------------->scope1 started here
//------v---------------------->this variable x is in scope1
    int x=5;  
    {//------------------------>scope2 started here
//----------v------------------>this variable x is in scope2
        int x= 6;
//------------v---------------->this prints scope2's x value        
        cout<<x;
    }//------------------------>scope2 ends here and x from scope2 is destroyed
//--------v---------------->this prints scope1's x value   
    cout<<x;
}//---------------->scope1 ends here
```

Also, the inner scope `x` is destroyed when that scope ends. Moreover, the inner scope `x` and outer scope `x` occupy different addresses in memory.

The output of the above program is `65` which can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/ioXEx6Hgw).

---

Additionally, note that `void main()` is not standard C++, you should instead replace it with `int main()` as shown in my above snippet.